# What is the best data type for storing a string of 2014-2015?

Tags: mysql, database, types

In my student database, I want to store school session which begins, for instance, April of every year and ends in March of the year following. And I want to store the session year as 2014-2015, 2015-2016 and so on. I am not sure which data type is most suitable for storing such string. Please help and suggest.

Comment: char with fixed length.. or i would suggest just number i.e. int you know the second range already but wont bet hat readable

Comment: I am using year(4) data type. But I have problem when Managing student alumni.

Comment: Another option would be to have two fields i.e. start and end session dates using year(4).

Comment: `But I have problem when Managing student alumni.` Please explain. Otherwise this seems like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the best data type for storing a string of 2014-2015?

It depends what you want to *do* with it. So to provide an answer, we've got to make some assumptions about that.

If you're *only* storing the string "2014-2015" to identify the session to a human viewer, then you can simply treat "2014-2015" as an arbitrary label for the session, no different from calling the session "Session 3", or "Frank". So saving it as a `VARCHAR` with an appropriate length should suffice.

If, however, you intend your system to have *logic* related to the *date range* represented by "2014-2015", i.e. to figure out if the "2014-2015" session comes before, after, or overlaps the "2015-2016" session, saving this as string data is suddenly a very bad idea.

Since it's reasonable that you might want to satisfy *both* of those requirements, I recommend separating the data: have a string field that identifies the session as "2014-2015" and have two `DATE` fields that identify the start and end dates of the session. This lets you use the correct data type in the correct context, without forcing you to write a lot of logic to convert between types as needed.

Answer (score 1):

For hundreds of rows, simply `CHAR(9) CHARACTER SET ascii`.

For millions of rows, consider these:

- `ENUM('2014-2015', '2015-2016', ...)` -- 1 byte
- `TINYINT UNSIGNED` (1 byte) and `JOIN` to a table with the strings in them
- `YEAR` (2 bytes), but then have the SELECTs 'construct' '2014-2015' from '2015'.